# NullPointerException at getArguments().getInten("index", index)

Tags: android

I'm presented with this unpleasant message on this code

```
public static HelpDetailsFragment newInstance(int index) 
{
    HelpDetailsFragment detailFragment = new HelpDetailsFragment();
    Bundle bundleArgs = new Bundle();
    bundleArgs.putInt("index", index);
    detailFragment.setArguments(bundleArgs);
    return detailFragment;
}   // newInstance()

public int getCurrentIndex()
{
    return getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
}
```

I'm using this code here:

```
HelpDetailsFragment detailFragment = (HelpDetailsFragment) getFragmentManager()
                          .findFragmentById(R.id.helpDetailsFrame);

    if((detailFragment == null) || (detailFragment.getCurrentIndex() != index))
    {
        detailFragment = HelpDetailsFragment.newInstance(index);
        Log.i(TAG, "HelpListFragment Create and replace details fragment for item:"+index);         
        FragmentTransaction fragTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragTrans.replace(R.id.helpDetailsFrame, detailFragment);
        fragTrans.commit(); 
    }
```

What em I missing here??

Comment: When are you calling `getCurrentIndex`? Could be too early

Comment: In this line:

    if((detailFragment == null) || (detailFragment.getCurrentIndex() != index))

Can you assure that `detailFragment` is not null?
Does `findFragmentById` return a valid reference? Or null?

Comment: Everything seems fine, Just make sure you are never creating instance except using `newInstance(int index)` method. Also just to avoid crash its always good idea for a null check on arguments, use this instead: `return getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("index", 0) : 0;`

Comment: I've read a bit in the sourcecode: it looks like arguments are always restored immediately so no fragment that is visible for you should ever have null arguments if you created it with arguments. Inside the Fragment itself it should only be null within the constructor.

Comment: return getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("index", 0) : 0
That did the trick!
As this code comes straight from the Android documentation, I wander why it's not there in the first place.  But anyway, thanks!